# Using Ajax to fetch a controller value

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have a Grails view that allows users to send invitations. When the view is called I set the variable

```
flash.invitation = [value from database]
```

. This is displayed in the view:

```
<h3>
<g:if test="${flash.numInvites > 1 || numInvites == 0}">
    You have ${flash.numInvites} invitations left
</g:if>
<g:else>
    You have ${flash.numInvites} invitation left
</g:else>
</h3>
```

Instead of using the flash context variable I would like to use Ajax to fetch the value from the database via a controller function.  For example:

```
def numberOfInvitesAjax() {
    String inviteStr = "error: no session"
    User user = getSessionUser()
    if (user != null) {
        int invites = user.invitations
        inviteStr = Integer.toString(invites)
    }
    render "${inviteStr}"
}
```

I can't figure out how to call this function when ever the page is rendered, however (my JavaScript fu is weak).

I have tried the remoteLink tag in grails, but this fetches the value only when there is a click, but not when the page is rendered. I've tried the remoteFunction but this didn't work for me either. Also, both of these tags are marked as deprecated to be removed from Grails in the future.

Any pointers on how to use grails to fetch a value when the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your controller method to return `XML` or `JSON` and fetch it using `JQuery` in one Ajax call:

```
def numberOfInvitesAjax() {
    String inviteStr = "error: no session"
    User user = getSessionUser()
    if (user != null) {
        int invites = user.invitations
        inviteStr = Integer.toString(invites)
    }
    def model = [message: inviteStr]
    render model as JSON
}
```

To organize your JavaScript code, you can create modules, in your `ApplicationResources.groovy`:

```
invitations {
  dependsOn 'jquery' //we need jquery to do the ajax calls
  resource url: 'js/invitations.js' //whatever structure you want 
}
```

In your JS file you can create a [Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals) with methods that will be used in your page. To do your ajax call, you can use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), something like:

```
var Invitations = {
  getNumberOfInvites : function(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
      //append the message in the element with id inviteMessage
      $('#inviteMessage').html(data.message);
    });
  }
};
```

And in your view, you need to load the resource module, and also call the function, passing the url of your controller action:

```
<!-- Load the javascript module -->
<head>
...
<r:require module="invitations" />
...
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <!-- we need this div to append the ajax message -->
   <div id='inviteMessage'></div>
   ...
   <!-- call functions when the page is ready -->
   <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function(){
       Invitations.getNumberOfInvites('${g.createLink(action:"numberOfInvitesAjax")}');
     });
   </script>
</body>
```